# How do I fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error in WordPress/Genesis Framework?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax-error, custom-wordpress-pages, genesis

I'm creating my first WordPress Genesis child theme. I'm trying to use the `get_theme_mod()` function to return two values from two custom controls I created on the WordPress back end. In `functions.php`, I have this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'gs_custom_theme_setting_background_image_1',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'gs_custom_theme_sanitize_bgi',
        )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize, 'gs_custom_image_bg_setting_1', array(
            'label' =>  __( 'Background Image 1st', 'gs-custom-theme' ),
            'settings' => 'gs_custom_theme_setting_background_image_1',
            'section' => 'gs_custom_theme_front_section',
            'priority' => 20
        )
    )
);


$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1',
        array(
            'default' => '#000000',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color'
        )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
        $wp_customize, 'gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1', array(
            'label' => __( 'Background Color 1', 'gs-custom-theme' ),
            'settings' => 'gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1',
            'section' => 'gs_custom_theme_front_section',
            'priority' => 15
        )
    )
);
```

This creates two custom settings  and two custom controls using the Theme Customizaion API (one color selector and one image selector). All I want to do is echo the hex value for whatever color I have selected and the URL for whatever image I have selected on my front page using the following in `front-page.php`:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod('gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1') ?>

<?php echo get_theme_mod('gs_custom_theme_setting_background_image_1') ?>
```

The color selector works perfectly fine and displays the hex value of whatever color I select as intended. However, when I try to use the image selector on the back end, not only does no image URL show up on my front page, but I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBOJf.png). I've looked around here and WordPress.org and this seems to be an issue related to javascript, but I haven't added any javascript to my site and I don't have any active plugins.

Anyone have any idea where to begin looking for this mystery syntax error?

Comment: Change the background image one to:

<?php echo get_theme_mod('gs_custom_theme_setting_background_image_1', true ); ?>

And I have never used the same control id as the settings id, but that might be why that one works and the other does not. Your control id "gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1" is the same as the setting "gs_custom_theme_setting_color_background_1". 

Also, I would use either Kirki(https://aristath.github.io/kirki/) or https://github.com/devinsays/customizer-library -- saves a lot of pain.